# Is using getDerivedStateFromProps in a uncontrolled Modal good practice

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to have all the hide and show logic within the error component, and only passing the initial show of the error modal when theres an error in my app like this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
             <ErrorModal show={!!this.state.error} message={this.state.error.message/>
          </div>
       )
     }
 }
```

Then in my ErrorModal, handle the closing of the error modal by using getDerivedStateFromProps.

```
class ErrorModal extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        title: 'Error',
        onClose: () => {}
    };

    state = { show: this.props.show };

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, previousState) {
        if(nextProps.show !== previousState.show) {
            return {show: nextProps.show};
        }

        return { show: previousState.show };
    }

    onClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            show: false
        }, this.props.onClose());
    };



    render() {
        const { message, children, title } = this.props;

        return (
            <GenericPopup show={this.state.show} className='error-modal'>
                <GenericPopup.Header>
                    <GenericPopup.Title>{title}</GenericPopup.Title>
                </GenericPopup.Header>
                <GenericPopup.Body>
                    { message ? message : children }
                </GenericPopup.Body>
                <GenericPopup.Footer>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" className='btn-primary close' onClick={this.onClose}>Okay, Got it.</a>
                </GenericPopup.Footer>
            </GenericPopup>
        )
    }
}
```

Is this the correct usage of getDerivedStateFromProps? Is there anotherway without having to make my component fully controlled?

Comment: If this.state.error changed in the app component, would that not re-render the app without the modal? I dont understand why you're trying to control it from within the ErrorModal componenet

Comment: And I'm pretty sure (not 100% though so correct me if I'm wrong) that the logic you're using inside of getDerivedStateFromProps isn't actually doing anything because the component will automatically update its state when the props change. Usually getDerivedStateFromProps is used like componentWillReceiveProps (being deprecated) was in that it's for if you want to decide manually if you want to change the state. But what you're doing here is saying that if the new props are different change the state to the new props, which is the default functionality of a component